# Is the Bembo font (or a close equivalent) available for LaTeX?

Tags: fonts

I'm currently writing my PhD thesis and was wondering if perhaps, the Bembo font was available in LaTeX?

What package should I load? (I obviously tried `\usepackage{bembo}` already but the `sty` is missing.)

The Bembo font is used by the Everyman's Library editions and I find it to be beautiful and comfortable for reading.

Is this font, or maybe a really close equivalent available for LaTeX. Also, my PhD is in the Mechanics field, so there is a large number of equations. Will there be problems (incompatibilities) with these fonts?

Any hints are appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Do you have the font installed on your computer? What kind of licence is does the font come with?

Comment: Bembo can only be used with `xelatex`  or `lualatex`

Comment: @jon I actually don't have the font installed, or at least I can't seem to find it...

Comment: @Herbert: I remember seeing documents typeset in Bembo with latex long before `xetex` was around.  So isn't it more the case that it's much more difficult/expensive to have Bembo without `xetex` or `luatex`

Comment: @Herbert I have an Everyman's book just before my eyes, and I could swear that it was typeset with LaTeX... but maybe I'm wrong...

Comment: You cannot _see_ it, if it was set with LaTeX or XeLaTeX. Only the font is imprortant, not the engine.

Comment: @Herbert -- digital renditions of Bembo have been around since the 1980s, when, for example, Monotype started releasing their phototype fonts in digital versions. And as *TeX has been able capable of using Type1 fonts since the olden days (correct me if necessary), there's no reason why there shouldn't be 20-yr old books typeset in Bembo using some TeX variant.

Comment: @NilsL: There is no official LaTeX-support for Bembo (tmf, enc, map, ... files), so it can only be used with LaTeX if someone writes his own support files. Without such files you can use it only with `XeTeX` or `LuaTeX`

Comment: I know :) ...and I know it's a very tedious thing to do -- which is why, e.g., Walter Schmidt deserves so much respect for his work. But still, a publisher or typesetting agency may do the same for Bembo, and decide *not* to release those support files publicly. That's what probably is the case, for example, with a [book](http://d-nb.info/963831895) lying on my desk, released in 2002, produced in  *TeX, using one of those horribly thin and anemic digital versions of Bembo as they used to be common in the 1990s.

Comment: @jrojasqu -- it's possible, but seems a bit unlikely to me that an Everyman's Library book would be produced in *TeX. Not because this would be a difficult thing to do, but simply because that field is dominated by typesetting engines other than *TeX. As I agree with Herbert -- you can hardly (!) ever tell by just looking at a random page -- I'd (seriously) like to know what indicators you had for this book being produced in *TeX.

Comment: @NilsL Well, as I said, I **surely** may be wrong. It is just that the titling, the footnotes, the spacings and every other single aesthetic aspect *looks* like it was typeset using Tex (I read a lot and it's the first time that I find such high resemblance, but it's all subjective)... All things said, you're right it wouldn't be normal to use a mathematician's tool to typeset a literature book...

Comment: I typeset books/documents with Bembo, New Aster or Garamond (for example) long before XeTeX and LuaTeX were available, and even without pdfTeX. As dvips supports Type1 fonts, that has been indeed feasible and done for many years.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try [`fbb`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/fbb):

> Derived from Cardo, provides a Bembo-like font family in otf and pfb format plus LaTeX font support files.

It's as simple as `\usepackage{fbb}` in recent TeX Live.

Comment: Just as remark: Is already included respectively can be installed with the Package Manager (both TL & MiKTeX).

Comment: This is the best answer: `fbb` is a version of Cardo, which is directly derived from Bembo, and has been specifically tailored for LaTeX use and is packaged with the TeXLive distribution.

Comment: The `fbb` font (Free Bembo) and the somewhat similar `etbb` font (ET Bembo) might not be what you want. These fonts have over-size glyphs, and thus are metrically very differnt from the commercial Bembo font and its imitators. You would need to carefully adjust font size, and also beware of lines that are closely spaced vertically (especially if with diacritical marks on uppercase).

Answer (score 26):

If the reason you'd like to use Bembo is your personal preference for »Renaissance« or »Humanist« typefaces, i.e. ones that bring across the aesthetics of the 1400s and 1500s -- there's two typefaces you should have a look at:

(1) the various digital renditions of Hermann Zapf's *Palatino* that are around, and (2) Robert Slimbach's *Minion*. Depending on how you look at a typeface (what aspects you're sensitive to), they may or may not be »close equivalents« to Bembo.

But since you seem to have to deal with a lot of math in your typesetting, your choices are somewhat limited anyways. I'd say the two fonts that best meet your three main requirements, that is

- share Bembo's look, to some degree
- be prepared to be used for math purposes (this is highly non-trivial)
- be readily available at no $$$ (right?)

are (1) *TeX Gyre Pagella,* which is a rendition of Palatino, ready to be used in *TeX, and equipped with math capabilities (math experts, feel free to correct me) -- and (2) *Minion Pro,* in OpenType format, of which eight cuts come as a give-away with Adobe's Reader.

This is how, as a non-Xe or Lua user, you would invoke the Pagella font:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tgpagella}
\begin{document}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

This is what Minion looks like (middle). I like it a lot more than Palatino, but that's personal taste I guess. It is, obviously, also closer to Bembo than Palatino is. There's the famous `minionpro` package which helps getting the font ready for use in pdfTeX. Plus there's the `mnsymbol` package to provice math symbols that go along better with a Renaissance face like Minion than do the standard symbols designed for the Classicist Computer Modern face.

[image: Minion]

For $108 by the way, you can license Bembo Book, (Regular, Regular Small Caps, Italic -- you wouldnt want to use a Bold with a 1400s typeface). If you really like Bembo and are looking for a professionally-crafted font that's versatile enough to be used in your life after the PhD, this might be something for you.

Comment: Thanks for the information! Although I think that the `Minion` option seems to be really appropriate for someone that wants Bembo but does not want to buy it. In my case, I finally got a hold of a complete Bembo typeface (we have a global license for Adobe products at work and the webmaster kindly updated my workstation's fonts). Only problem, I can't get it to work with LuaLatex, but that's another story. Thank you anyway, I tested your proposition and it works great!

Comment: It's very easy. In the firs time,you must install bembo in your computer. After, you will use it. In Mac computer, the name is {bembo std}

Comment: @jpayansomet I actually tried using `bembo std`, but it doesn't works... Also I checked the list of fonts generated by `luaotfload` and bembo doesn't appears anywhere...

Comment: I am surprised you omitted Garamond. Humanist typeface with math support in TeX --> `\usepackage[garamond]{mathdesign}`.

Comment: @mafp In fact, there is a package which has better text support: `\usepackage{garamondx}`. It's similar to Bembo and if you want math support, you can use `\usepackage[garamond]{mathdesign}` before.

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning the `mathastext` package in this context. Depending on the complexity of the mathematics, it might be an adequate half-way house...

Answer (score 21):

You may also want to consider the [Cardo](http://scholarsfonts.net/cardofnt.html) font, which may be downloaded free of charge. Its name is a contraction of the words "Card[inal Bemb]o"; Cardinal Bembo in the late 1490s commissioned and financed the publication of a book (entitled "De Aetna") printed by Aldus Manutius. The font face used for that book has come to be known simply as "Bembo". This font face has long been very highly regarded and celebrated for its design and overall readability. There have been many copies -- starting in the early 16th century, some more faithful to the original than others -- of Aldus Manutius' "Bembo" font face. `Cardo` is regarded as one of the more faithful copies of the "orginal Bembo" font face.

`Cardo` is an Opentype font, and its user guide describes it as a "font for scholars", i.e., a font that features lots and lots of glyphs. Moreover, in addition to the standard-weight upright font, it also features **bold** and *italic* font faces (but no ***bold&italic*** font face). Scroll to the bottom of the page indicated in the link above to find the link to the zip file that contains the three font files.

Comment: nice to see Cardo Italic has been released for good (I had given up 3 or 4 years ago). But I can't seem to find a download link for the OpenType version -- even though that version is mentioned a few times on that page :(

Comment: @NilsL  - you need to scroll to close to the bottom of the webpage. Look for the header line "HOW TO DOWNLOAD AND INSTALL" -- the link to the zip file `cardo104.zip` is just below that header. Upon unzipping the file, you'll find three font files in the directory `cardo104`.

Comment: I know -- downloading the [TrueType version](http://i.imgur.com/LNTOfsi.png) isn't a problem. Finding the .OTFs is ...but maybe the .TTFs are actually OpenType fonts in disguise. Will give it a closer look.

Comment: @Mico Thanks for the hint! Although I already gave Cardo a try... Don't get me wrong, I love the font, it's just that I don't know why it looks *really* medievalist (it's all really subjective in reality), and looks somewhat incompatible with the whole bunch of equations I'm throwing. Unfortunately I can't get myself to prefer it to the Bembo from Adobe (when combined with equations).

Comment: @NilsL I can confirm that the TTFs from Cardo are in fact OTFs in disguise, at least my computer says so. What's more, when compiling Cardo with LuaLaTeX I get absolutely zero problems, which is not the case with *real* TTFs that absolutely **refuse** to work!

Comment: @NilsL there’s some naming confusion going on here. OpenType simply means a font contains opentype tables. They may still have a .ttf file extension which is usually used to show that the bezier-splines in the font are quadratic (truetype splines), not cubic (cff splines).

Comment: @georgd I know -- but I do get things confused from time to time, partly because the term »OpenType font« is somewhat problematic in the first place. The way I see it: a so-called OpenType font is basically a collection of either good old truetype or cff outlines, put into a fancy container (the opentype tables) that may or may not be labeled as »OpenType« by the file extension. It may as well be a .ttf, hence my »OpenType fonts in disguise«.

Comment: The manual mentions (bottom of page 2 in manual for v1.04) that the font is "distributed as an OpenType with TrueType outlines (file extension .ttf, also known as True Type-flavor OT)."

Answer (score 11):

You can use it , if you have it, with xelatex or lualatex.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Bembo Std}

\begin{document}
Hello world
\end{document}
```

Comment: I feel like an idiot but, what do you mean by "if you have it"? Do you mean I must first download it or something? Is it that difficult to find it?

Comment: @jrojasqu: Bembo is not free, so it may not be already on your machine and you may need to pay to have it on your machine.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang Oh... didn't know that... thanks for the info...

Comment: @jrojasqu By the way, *Bembo Book* is more appropriate  if you are going to print it.

Comment: @jpayansomet: You're welcome.  I was called away so I didn't get a chance to explain.  Use four spaces to indent code and it will be formatted as such.  Also, the `minimal` class isn't for minimal examples.  `article` is fine.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang @jpayansomet I finally got a hold of the Bembo typeface, so I have it and installed it... Only problem is that I can't get it to work with LuaLatex... seems like `fontspec` or `luaotfload` can't find it! Also, the math became all messy...

Comment: Installation is machine-specific, so I can't help.  Here is a blog post by a guy who did it: http://onlyamodel.com/2012/thesis-typography-bembo-gill-sans/

Comment: And also there is Cardo, which is a free copy (not bold/italic, if I remember well, but may be it works).

Answer (score 8):

Try "EB Garamond".  You can download free as a Google Web font.   In spite of its name saying Garamond in the title it is almost a prefect clone of Bembo.  See this font sample (with typo "EB Garomond"): http://joelcrawfordsmith.com/new/font/bembo (I had to find it for a client recently).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: It is actually much better: There is already a LaTeX package `ebgaramond` containing font files in Type1 and Opentype.

Comment: It is a great font - I personally prefer it to Bembo, but for the particularly picky,  (as evidenced in the link provided), it is not quite "almost a perfect clone" as suggested here

Answer (score 8):

In addition to Andy's answer:

- A great advantage of fbb over Cardo is that it has kerning tables.
- fbb is just as easily used with LuaLaTeX; just install the package and write

  `\usepackage{fontspec}`

  `\setmainfont{fbb}`

Its OpenType features can be inspected with fontforge.

Alternatively, Edward Tufte has kindly made the version of Bembo designed for his books available in TrueType format on github, under an MIT licence. It has been renamed ET Book to avoid conflicts:
https://github.com/edwardtufte/et-book

Answer (score 3):

There is a free font almost identical to Bembo: [Bergamo](http://fontsite.com/store/bergamo-pro/). Also consider [Crimson](http://www.aldusleaf.org/0-crimson.html), along the lines of Minion, Sabon and Garamond.

Comment: The link says the font costs money.

Comment: But (today at least, like the previous comment), the Regular, Bold, Italic and Bold Italic are free. (But I agree with another commenter on this page that Bembo and bold do not go together well.)

Answer (score 3):

And then there is `ETbb` by the same Michael Sharpe who made `fbb` earlier.  He writes that he believes `ETbb` is closer in appearance to Edward Tufte's font usage in his books than `fbb`.  In the [documentation](https://mirror.math.princeton.edu/pub/CTAN/fonts/etbb/doc/ETbb-doc.pdf), he gives a detailed suggestion for what math font would go well with `ETbb`.

Comment: What a nice discovery!